# Trouble with compilation in Store in Windows Phone 8

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I'm presenting a problem. I have built an application that has Win32 libraries that do not belong to the subset that has in common with WinRT. From my computer I can deploy the application and working properly. But when I go to the store my application is compiled with WinRT preventing several of the features work correctly.

In turn, the problem that would be working blind because we would never know from the development environment if we are building the application works perfectly until published in up tent.

Is there any chance from the development environment that I can detect which libraries would not work once compiled into the store?

Greetings ... Jorge